# How to load local file via fetch on server side in Nuxt3 project

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxt3

In a Nuxt3 project, the following component method returns data as expected:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    async getPodcasts() {
      return await $fetch('_nuxt/assets/data/podcasts.json')
    }
  }
```

However, when I try to load the same data through a server-side file (`server/api/podcasts/index.get.js`) like so:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  return await fetch('_nuxt/assets/data/podcasts.json')
})
```

I get the following error:

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Failed to parse URL from _nuxt/assets/data/podcasts.json
```